# Use Multipart while uploading

Tags: google-drive-api

I am not using sdk of google drive 
I want to upload a file on my google drive account thr my app for which I have used post api to which I have set url,headers,filename.But I get error as 'Bad content type.Use multipart'.
My code is as follows-

File file = new File(fileName);

String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files/" + file.getName() + "?uploadType=multipart&access_token=" + accessToken;

headers.put("Content-type", "multipart/related");

response = GlobalConstants.SERVICE_CLIENT.Execute(url, "post", file, headers); //call to post.

Please do help at ur earliest
Thnx in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to read and understand this page https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert.

Try the "try it now" link (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert#try-it) and look at how the URL and payload is formed, then your app needs to recreate that. The URL in your code is nothing like the URL required by the Drive API.

Comment: Hey thnx for responding,
My updated code is as follows


String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart&access_token=" + accessToken;

headers.put("Content-type", "multipart/related");
headers.put("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));

response = GlobalConstants.SERVICE_CLIENT.Execute(url, "post", file, headers);
                
jsonFile = new JSONObject(response);


Still I get error as 'bad content use multitype' and file is not being uploaded.
Headers and url are as per documentation.

Comment: If I keep headers blank then file is being uploaded but is 'Untitled' and in response mimetype of the file is 'application/octet-stream' always

File contains data but without its original title and extension.
Please do help and thnx in advance

Comment: I need to see the actual URL and request, rather than your code. Can you trace the http either using debugging or a proxy

Comment: URL -  https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart&access_token=ya29.AHES6ZR2SceJ-fdgNzK1dsDP56YCjR2D2BBjggQfrCgPZQ

Request - We are trying to upload content of file in request

If I put accessToken in 'Authorization' as per the doc '401' error is encountered. Even thought accessToken is not expired and is valid

Comment: Turn on logging with "Logger.getLogger(HttpTransport.class.getName()).setLevel(Level.CONFIG);". This will capture the request and response and provide some clue why it's not working.